# border-box not working with overflow

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a blue hexagon using 3 rectangles. I rotate each rectangle and want to use `overflow:hidden` so that only the blue rectangle remains. This works well in chrome but not in safari.

here is the code snippet:

```css
  .hex {
    width: 22%;
    padding-bottom:25.04%;
    display:block;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(120deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(120deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(120deg);
    transform: rotate(120deg);
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .hex2 {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-60deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-60deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(-60deg);
  }
  
  .hexIn-2 {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-60deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-60deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(-60deg);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
```

```html
<div style="widht:100%;margin:10%">

  <div class="hex">
    <div class="hex2">
      <div class="hexIn-2">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

When I run it in Chrome I get the desired result, a blue hexagon:

[image]

and when I run it in safari I get this, as you can see the `overflow:hidden` is not working since the other two rectangles go outside the red one.

[image]

I think the problem is that they are within the padding of the div that contains the red rectangle and that `box-sizing:border-box` is not working properly. Any ideas?

Comment: FYI, this works great even in IE (11), so...Safari is probably the worst (popular) browser, ever! :)

Comment: @sinisake good to know it even works in IE! Also fails on my phone, both in the Chrome app and Safari though :(

Comment: Hope you are using safari on Mac, and not on windows, because safari is no more supported on windows, there is no more update since 2012 , so lots of css properties not works on windows safari.

Comment: Didn't you miss `position:relative` along with `overflow:hidden`? AFAIK you can't use `overflow` unless element is positioned. (can't test myself, in Safari 5 on windows this works)

Comment: Also you may try `position:absolute` and `clip:rect(auto,auto,auto,auto)` instead of `overflow:hidden`. Won't post it as answer because I can't check it either.

Comment: @Denis Sheremet Yes! it works with `position:relative`. I didn't know you that the element had to be positioned before I could use `overflow`. Thanks!!